# What does a team captain in chess do?

Tags: preparation

I was made the "team captain" of the chess club I am a member of for a match with a chess club in a different city.I want to know all the requirements for being a team captain.All I did was choose the team members based on the highest rating.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see what FIDE says, [Team Captain’s Role in Team Tournaments](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=20&view=category):

> **(a)** The role of a team captain is basically an administrative one
>   during play. Depending on the regulations of the specific competition,
>   the captain shall be required to deliver at a specific time a written
>   list naming the players in his team participating in each round, to
>   communicate to his players their pairing, to sign the protocol
>   indicating the results in the match at the end of the play, etc.
>
> **(b)** Whenever the team captain speaks to one of his players, he should
>   do so only through or in the presence of an arbiter, using a language
>   the arbiter can understand.
>
> **(c)** A captain is entitled to advise the players of his team to make or
>   accept an offer of a draw or to resign a game, unless the regulations
>   of the event stipulate otherwise. He must confine himself only to
>   brief information, based solely on the circumstances pertaining to the
>   match. He may say to a player, “offer a draw”, “accept the draw”, or
>   “resign the game”. For example, if asked by a player whether he should
>   accept an offer of a draw, the captain should answer “yes”, “no”, or
>   delegate the decision to the player himself. He shall give no
>   information to a player concerning the position on the chess board
>   and/or the clock times, nor consult any other person and/or computer
>   as to the state of the game. The captain shall refrain from any
>   intervention during play.
>
> **(d)** Players are subject to the same prohibitions. Even though in a
>   team competition there is a certain team loyalty, which goes beyond a
>   player’s individual game, a game of chess is basically a contest
>   between two players. Therefore a player must have the final say over
>   the conduct of his own game. Although the advice of the captain should
>   weigh heavily with the player, the player is not absolutely compelled
>   to accept that advice. Likewise, the captain cannot act on behalf of a
>   player and his game without the knowledge and consent of the player.
>
> **(e)** A team captain should encourage his team always to follow both the
>   letter and the spirit of Article 12 of the FIDE Laws of Chess
>   concerning the conduct of the players. Team championships, in
>   particular, should be conducted in the spirit of the highest
>   sportsmanship.

A player which has highest rating and better knowledge about rules is the best candidate to be a captain.

Comment: So, the captains won't play?

Comment: @Dineshkumar: They will. Only players are allowed to be in the competition place during games, the captain is one of them.

Comment: And if the captain is also playing and is called by another player about accepting or not a draw offer can s/he stop the clock?